# How do I access the transclude function from a directive link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Short question**
How do I get access to the transclude function within a directive link function using Angular 1.1.1?

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Here is the (broken) fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/michaeldausmann/7NXZs/

I am trying to write a 'wrapper' directive...

```
<wrapper-dynamic>
    <h2>Wrap me Dynamically!</h2>
</wrapper-dynamic>
```

...the dynamic template will contain an ng-transclude...

```
var tmpl = "<div>Dynamic Wrapper version {{wrapperVersion}}</div><hr/><div ng-transclude></div>";
```

...and I am $compiling it in the link function....

```
var thing = $compile(tmpl)(scope)
element.append(thing);
```

This fails with an error...."undefined is not a function"

I think I need to pass a transclude function to the $compile...

$compile(tmpl, transcludefn)(scope)

but I'm not sure how to access the transclude function... it does not appear to be available in the link function parameters like it is in **later** versions of angular.

Michael

Comment: what exactly is broken with the fiddle?

Comment: Short question: Why are you using such an old verion of Angular ?

Comment: Matt, the dynamic version of the directive was throwing an 'undefined is not a function' error.  Expert, I'm building the directive for a large application that uses the earlier version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before AngularJS 1.2 you had to define the `compile` function to get a reference to the `transclude` function:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {

  return {
    transclude: true,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {

      return function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {

        console.log(transcludeFn);

      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/cNfwlf1RgMiDTASiLNIJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks tasseKATT, you are right, I needed to use the compile function.  I also updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/michaeldausmann/7NXZs/1/